# Problem on Definite Integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, integral-equations

Q. Find all the values of $ 'a' $ which satisfy the equation: $$ ∫_{0}^{\frac{π}{2}} \left(\sin \left(x\right) + a\cos \left(x\right)\right)^3 dx - \frac{4a}{π-2} ∫_{0}^{\frac{π}{2}} x\cos \left(x\right) dx =2  $$

**My Attempt**: I tried to integrate the expression though I got the integral of $$ ∫_{0}^{\frac{π}{2}} x\cos \left(x\right) dx $$ But I am Clueless to integrate $$ ∫_{0}^{\frac{π}{2}} \left(\sin \left(x\right) + a\cos \left(x\right)\right)^3 dx $$ So please help me with that integral. Although I feel there must be another method where finding the integral is not necessary. Does any method exist? If it does, would you please share it to me ?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Integral of $\int_{0}^{\frac{π}{2}} xcosx dx $ is $ xsinx + cosx $ (using Bipart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that by the change of variable $y=\dfrac\pi2-x$,

$$I(a):=\int_0^{\pi/2}(\sin x+a\cos x)^3dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}(\cos y+a\sin y)^3dy=a^3J(a^{-1}).$$

This shows that $I(a)$ is a cubic polynomial (by expanding the cube and integrating) with symmetric coefficients ($p+qa+qa^2+pa^3$) and you can spare two integral evaluations.

Among the terms of the development, 
$$p=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^3x\,dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin x\sin^2x\,dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\color{blue}{\sin x}\,dx-\int_0^{\pi/2}\color{blue}{\sin x\cos^2x}\,dx=1-\frac13=\frac23$$

and
$$q=3\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin x\cos^2x\,dx=3\cdot\frac13$$ as already computed, which gives

$$I(a)=\frac{2+3a+3a^2+2a^3}3.$$

Now by parts,

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}x\color{blue}{\cos x}\,dx=\frac\pi2\sin\frac\pi2-\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin x\,dx=\frac\pi2-1.$$

The equation is

$$\frac{2+3a+3a^2+2a^3}3-2a=2.$$

By inspection, $$2a^3+3a^2-3a-4=0$$ has the solution $a=-1$, and by long division it factors as

$$(a+1)(2a^2+a-4).$$

---

I don't think there is a way to avoid explicit computation of the coefficients, but a careful strategy reduces the integration effort to very little (actually just the three easy functions in blue).

Comment: Got It! Thanks a bunch ! Though I think Walli's formula too will reduce the integration effort a little!

Comment: @CreepAnonymous: do you really need Wallis to integrate $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ ??

Comment: It may help for $sin^3x$ and etc!

Comment: So elegant ! Thanks for it + shame on me. Cheers.

Comment: @CreepAnonymous: yep, but my main goal was to show how to *avoid* these integrals.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: hi Claude. Just my usual laziness sin ;-)

Comment: @Yves Got that one! Your solution seem to really help me!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If you expand
$A=(\sin (x)+a \cos (x))^3$ you should get, 
$$A=\frac{1}{4} a^3 \cos ^3(x)+\frac{3}{4} a^3 \cos (x)-\frac{3}{4} a^3 \sin
   ^2(x) \cos (x)-\frac{3}{4} a^2 \sin ^3(x)+\frac{3}{4} a^2 \sin
   (x)+$$ $$\frac{9}{4} a^2 \sin (x) \cos ^2(x)-\frac{3}{4} a \cos
   ^3(x)+\frac{3}{4} a \cos (x)+\frac{9}{4} a \sin ^2(x) \cos (x)+$$ $$\frac{\sin
   ^3(x)}{4}+\frac{3 \sin (x)}{4}-\frac{3}{4} \sin (x) \cos ^2(x)$$ When integrating, the only problem is really with $\int \cos^3(x) \,dx$ and $\int \sin^3(x) \,dx$ but
$$\int \cos^3(x) \,dx=\int \cos(x) (1-\sin^2(x)) \,dx$$
$$\int \sin^3(x) \,dx=\int \sin(x) (1-\cos^2(x)) \,dx$$ for which there is obvious subtitution.

Comment: Thanks! All good, Though I was expecting an answer without expansion! That means expansion is necessary isn't it??

Comment: @CreepAnonymous. I do think so ! Another way would be to use $\sin(x)+a \cos(x]=\frac{\sin(x+\theta)} {\cos(\theta)}$ with $\theta=\tan^{-1}(a)$ to get for the antiderivative $\sec ^3(\theta ) \left(\frac{1}{12} \cos (3 (\theta +x))-\frac{3}{4} \cos
   (\theta +x)\right)$ which is $\frac{1}{12} \left(a^2+1\right)^{3/2} \left(\cos \left(3 \left(\tan
   ^{-1}(a)+x\right)\right)-9 \cos \left(\tan ^{-1}(a)+x\right)\right)$

Comment: Nice approach! Thanks